# Vue: Should I return a blank function in a computed property?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am passing in a function as a prop `completedRejectionAssetsUpload` for some instances of a component and use it for an event `@vdropzone-queue-complete` on Dropzone image uploader.
For other instances, I don't want/need that prop.
I am using a computed property to see if the prop is available and if so, the event function works fine.
However on the instances where I don't pass in the prop, I get `[Vue warn]: Invalid handler for event "vdropzone-queue-complete": got null`, which makes sense since I am just using `return;` in this instance.  What is the proper way to handle this -- should I make an "empty" function to just make it work?

```html
<vue-drop-zone 
  ref="myVueDropzone" 
  id="dropzone" 
  :options="dropzoneOptions" 
  :useCustomSlot=true 
  @vdropzone-queue-complete="this.computedCompletion"
>
```

```js
props: {
    completedRejectionAssetsUpload: {type: Function}
},
computed: {
     computedCompletion() {
            if (this.completedRejectionAssetsUpload) {
                return this.completedRejectionAssetsUpload;
            } else {
                return;
                /// need to return something so the event doesn't throw warning
            },
     }  
}
```

Comment: u can't use `this` from template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I really dislike passing in functions as props since it sort of violates the [one-way data flow principal](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow) but that's just my opinion.

What you should do is define a default prop value for when it has not been defined.

For example

```js
props: {
  completedRejectionAssetsUpload: {
    type: Function,
    default: () => {}
  }
}
```

```html
<vue-drop-zone 
  ref="myVueDropzone" 
  id="dropzone" 
  :options="dropzoneOptions" 
  :useCustomSlot=true 
  @vdropzone-queue-complete="completedRejectionAssetsUpload"
>
```

---

A better option IMO is to emit an event

```html
<vue-drop-zone 
  ref="myVueDropzone" 
  id="dropzone" 
  :options="dropzoneOptions" 
  :useCustomSlot=true 
  @vdropzone-queue-complete="queueComplete"
>
```

```js
methods: {
  queueComplete ($event) {
    this.$emit('uploaded', $event)
  }
}
```

Then parent components can choose whether or not to listen for that event

```html
<UploadComponent @uploaded="handleUploadedEvent">
```

Comment: didn't know you can set a default value for function prop, thanks.  Is there a specific reason you don't like it?  I'm interested in the alternatives.  Maybe using an emitter?